# How can I ask to have my closed question reopened?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, closed-questions, privileges

I've got a [question that hasn't been reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25028660/456814) after some users put it on hold as unclear, I want to know when that right is gained.

Also how can I ask for my questions to be reopened? What happens when someone flags a question?

Comment: People can vote to close at 3k rep.  Editing the question will put it into a reopen queue.

Comment: Ahhh, what can i do if i just need one more vote to reopen it?

Comment: You just wait - it's in the queue, so if it only needs one more vote then it shouldn't be long before someone sees it and casts the final vote. And..... it's now been reopened. In future make sure your question is clear from the outset so that people don't have to close it.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, @Fish. Though definitely close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As stated in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), users gain the privilege to vote to close (and reopen) questions when they reach 3000 reputation.

[As mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267599/when-do-users-earn-the-privilege-to-vote-to-close-questions#comment71719_267599), editing a closed question will place it in the reopen review queue, where other 3000+ rep users can either vote to reopen the question, or kick it out of the review queue in its closed state by marking it as "Leave Closed".

So when you edit a closed question, if you want it to be placed in the Reopen review queue to be reopened, *then make sure that you make that first edit count*. Make sure that you address *all* of the issues in the question with that first edit, otherwise the question might be kicked-out of the queue early if you make a trivial edit that doesn't address the fundamental issues of the closed question.

As for what happens when a question is flagged, that depends on what flag is used. There is no flag for reopening a question, and definitely ***do not flag a moderator*** if all you want is for your question to be reopened, because moderators have more important things to do, and they will usually not reopen your question except perhaps (maybe) in ***exceptional*** circumstances (do not count on this, it is very unlikely to happen).

### Additional reopen options

If you think your question should be reopened, you also have the options of of bringing the question up for discussion here on Meta or in one of the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

**Beware**, however, that if you bring your question up for discussion on Meta, and it *isn't* fit to be reopened, then some Meta users may decide to apply additional downvotes to your question, and maybe even vote to delete it.

You will have a greater chance of success of having a constructive discussion on Meta about the possibility of reopening your question if you're open-minded to the possibility that you're question really *should* be closed in its present form. Don't make demands or automatically assume that your question should be reopened. Perhaps ask about possible ways to edit or improve your question so that it *can* be reopened.

Your attitude towards how you approach asking to have your question reopened can make a significant difference in terms of the kind of response you receive on Meta. Humility can go a *long* way towards a positive outcome.

#### Chat rooms

Additionally, **be very cautious** about bringing your question up for discussion in one of the chat rooms, if that is the route that you choose to try to bring more attention to your question. Not all chat rooms are receptive to discussion of questions that may be of poor quality, and you may even receive a hostile response.

If you want to try discussing your question in a chat room, I recommend that you try the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Discussions about questions are common in that chat room, and the users are generally receptive to such discussion, though they may not ultimately vote to reopen your question, if they don't think that it should be reopened.